# Jquery .load / .resizable not working

Tags: jquery, resize, load

Why does the resize work in this function and not work in the function below.
It's important for me because everytime when the div with id #test gets clicked i want the data to be retrieved and not just once in the beginning (working example).

Thanks.

WORKS

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#tc").load("berichten.php");
  $("#tc").draggable();
  $("#test").click( function(){
    $("#tc").toggle(); //.css("display","inline-block");
    $("#tc").resizable();
  });
});
```

NOT WORKS !!! :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tc").draggable();
  $("#test").click(function(){
    $("#tc").load("berichten.php");
    $("#tc").toggle(); //.css("display","inline-block");
    $("#tc").resizable();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your `.load()` function is async, probably has something to do with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#tc").load("berichten.php", function(){
    $("#tc").toggle(); //.css("display","inline-block");
    $("#tc").resizable();
});
```

Utilize the callback function of the `.load()` to only respond once the request has been completed.

Comment: Thank you.. Also thanks to all the other solutions but this one fits the best for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that the default action of click on your link cancels the loading. Try:

```
$("#test").click( function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#tc").load("berichten.php");
  $("#tc").toggle(); //.css("display","inline-block");
  $("#tc").resizable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tc").draggable();
  $(document).on("click","#test",function(){
    $("#tc").load("berichten.php");
    $("#tc").toggle(); //.css("display","inline-block");
    $("#tc").resizable();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the data using `AJAX` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var el = $('#tc');
    el.draggable();
    var AjaxRequest = null;
    $("#test").click(function() {
        if (AjaxRequest !== null) {
            AjaxRequest.abort();
        }
        AjaxRequest = $.get('berichten.php', function(data) {
            el.html(data);
            el.toggle(); //.css("display","inline-block");
            el.resizable();
        });
    });
});
```